# how to stack pm3d multiplot in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Using gnuplot, I would like to stack 5 contour plots together, meaning no white spaces between them. I can't get it to work for some reason. any help is appreciated.

```
#! /usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal epslatex color size 7in,2in 
set output "s.pdf"
set multiplot layout 1,5

set lmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set rmargin 0

set size square
set pm3d map

unset colorbox 
unset key

set format x "";
set format y "";
set xlabel "";
set ylabel "";
splot x*x+y*y 
splot x*x+y*y
splot x*x+y*y
splot x*x+y*y
splot x*x+y*y

unset multiplot
```

is there a way to do it without adjusting a position of each plot? it works for normal plots like here http://gibuu.physik.uni-giessen.de/GiBUU/wiki/HowToGnuplotStacked but not for pm3d